# Is there a way to get complete API signature of REST Api Inside the method implementing @Path

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs, spring-rest

As the title suggests, I have Spring methods implementing REST and spring REST annotations `@Path` 
I want to get the complete signature of the API made to get to that method I mean the complete signature
For instance

```
@Path("/customer/{id}")
method(String id){}
```

in there a way I can get the complete signature like: `http://host:port/customer/1`  inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the `{id}` using the annotation [@PathParam](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggqny/index.html):

```
@Path("/customer/{id}")
public method(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: That won't solve the problem, I need the Complete API signature that leads to calling of that method as I have explained. I need to get "http://host:port/customer/1" the complete signature

Answer (score 0):

You can just inject [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) and use the method [`getAbsolutePath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getAbsolutePath--).

```
@GET
@Path("/customer/{id}")
public Response get(@PathParam("id") String id, @Context UriInfo info) {
    String absPath = info.getAbsolutePath().toString();
}
```

As an aside, please take some time to learn the difference between Spring MVC (REST) and Jersey (JAX-RS). Your question seems to suggest that you think they might be the same thing, which they definitely are not.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question.

```
 @Path("/customer/{id}")
 @Get
 public ResponseEntity<String> getCustomer(
           @PathParam("id") String id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());                
    return ResponseEntity.ok(id);
}
```

Along with the Path param argument, we need to add `HttpServletRequest` which carries the whole information about that particular request.

Here `request.getRequestURL()` gives complete request url path. For example `http://localhost:8080/testApp/customer/1`.

Hope this helps.